# Each type name in a schema must be unique. Code first

Tags: c#, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm trying to update my database Code first but I get this error after Run add-migration command

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

ServicioTest.ErrorDispositivo: Name: Each type name in a schema must be 
unique. Type name 'ErrorDispositivo' is already defined.
```

I've tried a lot of possible solutions:

- Clean and rebuild
- Delete Migrations folder and tables in database
- Change connection string name
- Delete bin folder and then rebuild

But doesn't work.

My data is

```
public class ModeloDatos : DbContext
{

    public ModeloDatos()
        : base("name=ModeloDatos")
    {
    }
    public virtual DbSet<Dispositivos> Dispositivos { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Solicitud> Solicitudes { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Aplicacion> Aplicaciones { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Log> Logs { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ErrorDispositivo> ErroresDispositivo { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<FormatoTemplate> FormatosTemplate { get; set; }
}

[Table("Dispositivos")]
public class Dispositivos
{
    [Key]
    public string DispositivoID { get; set; }

    //propiedad de navegacion
    public virtual ICollection<Solicitud> Solicitudes { get; set; }
}



[Table("Solicitudes")]
public class Solicitud
{
    //primary key
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int SolicitudID { get; set; }
    public DateTime Fecha { get; set; }
    public string Ip { get; set; }


    public string DispositivoID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("DispositivoID")]
    public virtual Dispositivos Dispositivo { get; set; }


    public Respuesta DatosRespuesta { get; set; }


}


[Table("Aplicaciones")]
public class Aplicacion
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Usuario { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    public string Clave { get; set; }

    public Guid Codigo { get; set; }

    public bool Habilitado { get; set; }

}

[Table("Logs")]
public class Log
{
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
    public string StackTrace { get; set; }
}

[ComplexType]
public class Respuesta
{

    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Codigo")]
    public virtual ErrorDispositivo TipoErrorDispositivo { get; set; }


    public string Mensaje { get; set; }
    public string FingerPrint1 { get; set; }
    public string FingerPrint2 { get; set; }


}

[Table("ErrorDispositivos")]
public class ErrorDispositivo
{
    [Key]
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Descripcion { get; set; }
}


[Table("FormatoTemplates")]
public class FormatoTemplate
{
    [Key]
    public int Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Formato { get; set; }
}
```

How can I solve this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the issue will be with the complex type and

```
public virtual ErrorDispositivo TipoErrorDispositivo { get; set; }
```

You cannot have navigation properties within the complex type. This should be pulled out to the entities that need this relationship.